# Mystery with bool data type

Tags: c, boolean

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{
bool a[5]={0,1,0,0,0};
a[1]=3;
printf("\n bool is %d",a[1]);
printf("\n sizeof bool is %d and size of a is %d",sizeof(bool),sizeof(a));

bool b[10];
printf("\n bool is %d",b[1]);

}
```

**output of this program is**

```
 bool is 1
 sizeof bool is 1 and size of a is 5
 bool is 4
```

**Question :**

1> bool store 1 bit then why sizeof(bool) is 1 byte ?

2> if bool has 1 byte then when i assign a[1] = 3 then why it print 1 ?

3> if bool only consider 1 & o value to be store then why b[1] prints value 3 ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1> Bool store is not 1 bit. Nothing is 1 bit. Everything is at least 1 byte. `sizeof(bool)` is platform specific. Only `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1.

2> It implicitly converts `int` to `bool` : `(bool)3 == 1`

3> the array `b` is not initialized, it can have any value. You're just accessing some memory.

Comment: clean and clear, except one doubt,
The byte, in storage memory, will be `00000001` or `11111111` for 1 ?

Comment: "Everything is at least 1 byte" --> What about fields in a structure?

Answer (score 1):

The reason the last printf prints a 4, is because the `b` array is not initialized, which means the printf-function just takes whatever value is already in the memory.

Answer (score 0):

In C there is no real boolean type. C interprets an integer to mean `false` if it is 0 and everything else as true. Even though a bool would only require a single bit, this is never used in practice as the smallest addressable unit in most architectures is a byte. Instead of going down the route of masking all but one bits in a byte the approach I explained above is used.

You are using `stdbool.h` from C99 which is providing a typedef `bool` and the macros `true` and `false`. The macros expand to 0 and 1 respectively but make the source more descriptive. The `sizeof` is implementation defined and you cannot rely on it to be the same on different platforms.

Comment: There's more to C than just C89.

Comment: @Luc I added a paragraph for `stdbool.h`

Comment: This is tagged as both C++ and C so presumably the bool from stdbool.h is name clashing with the real boolean type "bool" from C++ ...

Comment: @Benj How would they clash? If `stdbool` is included bool is expanded to _Bool in preprocessing stage. No clashes possible here.

Comment: That rather depends on what is meant by clash, I simply meant that bool's native behavior with regard to the C++ compiler (which is presumably being used) is being overridden.

Comment: @Benj You should ask OP about this. All I see is C code using C headers and a C tag. Also I interpret `clash` to mean `to be in conflict`. When something is cleanly overridden, there is no conflict. :)

Comment: @pmr - Look more closely, that code wouldn't compile if it wasn't a C++ compiler ;-)

Comment: @Benj I'm not too keen to continue this discussion, but `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -ansi -std=c99` accepts the code and I don't see why it shouldn't.

Comment: @pmr Apologies, I'm still using an old C compiler, didn't realise C99 allows you to declare variables mid block.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4354/discussion-between-pmr-and-benj)