# Why does printing an uninitialized bool array as integers produce values besides 0 and 1?

Tags: c

(Also see [Mystery with bool data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7804804/mystery-with-bool-data-type) for a similar question with relevant answers.)

---

While debugging a program, I noticed strange output when printing an uninitialized bool array as integers. Consider this C program:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n = 30;
    bool* bools = malloc(n * sizeof(bool)); // Uninitialized memory.
    for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
    {
        int x = bools[i];
        assert(x == 0 || x == 1);
        printf("%d ", x);
    }
    printf("\n");
    free(bools);
}
```

Due to the uninitialized bool array, the output varies with each run based on previous memory contents, of course. My understanding is that casting a bool to an int should always produce either 0 or 1 (see the assertion above, which always passes); however, I frequently see output like this:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 144 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 144 16 0 92 113 255 127 0 0 160 41 222 134 255 127
```

Can someone explain how this program can print anything besides 0s and 1s?

**Update:** The short answer is that casting an *uninitialized* bool to int can produce values besides 0 and 1. (In my case, bools are stored as bytes, so their uninitialized values can be anything in [0..255].) Also, the assert line above seems to be optimized out, which made this problem more difficult to debug.

---

To provide a little more context: I was originally writing a function to count the number of set bits in a bool array, e.g.:

```
int popcount(const bool* v, int n)
{
    int c=0;
    for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) c += v[i];
    return c;
}
```

I noticed that sometimes this would return a result **greater** than n, which seemed impossible. The problem was that the bool array was uninitialized. Zeroing the array fixed the problem, but it still doesn't make sense to me how casting a bool to an int could produce something besides 0 or 1.

Comment: Since accessing uninitialized data results in undefined behavior, any result is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it doesn't make sense to restrict boolean read operations to clamp the actual value to either 0 or 1.

The value of an undefined variable can be anything that fits within the variable's size. A `bool` usually occupies a single byte (because that's the smallest addressable unit), and on systems with 8-bit bytes it means a `bool` can store 256 different values. That's why the numbers you're seeing range from 0 to 255.

The implementation is free to assume that you will not invoke UB, that's why you're seeing values besides 0 and 1. In code without UB, all `bool`s would convert to either 0 or 1.

Comment: That explains why it prints values more than 1, but why doesn't the `assert` ever fire?

Comment: @Barmar it is optimized out by the compiler, as a valid `bool` should not contain something else than `0` or `1`. Optimizations are allowed to consider that undefined behaviour never occurs.

Answer (score 2):

A `bool` (`_Bool`) object can only hold values `0` or `1`. In your case your program invokes undefined behavior as you are accessing uninitialized memory returned by `malloc` which has indeterminate value.

A strictly conforming program will only evaluate `_Bool` objects to `0` or `1`.